# border black cell of header in CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc

I have my derived class of header that changes header of `CListCtrl`, with this code I change color of header and the written is black, I would like to change border of my cell in my header

```
void MyHeader::OnNMCustomdraw(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMCUSTOMDRAW pNMCD = reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(pNMHDR);
       
    *pResult = CDRF_DODEFAULT;

    NMLVCUSTOMDRAW *pCD = (NMLVCUSTOMDRAW*)pNMHDR; 

    if (pNMCD->dwDrawStage == CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT)
    {
        HDITEM hditem;
        TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
        SecureZeroMemory(&hditem, sizeof(HDITEM));
        hditem.mask = HDI_TEXT;
        hditem.pszText = buffer;
        hditem.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;
        GetItem(pNMCD->dwItemSpec, &hditem);
        CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(pNMCD->hdc);
        pDC->SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(251, 206, 177));
        CString str(buffer);
                
        pDC->DrawText(str, CRect(pNMCD->rc), DT_VCENTER | DT_LEFT);
        *pResult = CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, where is the `if` before the `else if`? Also [edit] and show picture of what you want vs. what you get.

Comment: sorry it's an error, in my code there isn't "else"

Comment: ...well then [edit] the question and show your _actual_ code.

Comment: You may have your life made a bit easier, if you use `CMFCListCtrl` instead. I don't work with MFC anymore, but when I did, I remember I wanted to have custom headers on the grids, and it was easier.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are skipping the default drawing, you might as well just draw your border right after `pDC->DrawText(...)`, whatever color / shape you want.